# Jmeter Data Compare for functional testing

Tags: jmeter, functional, api-testing

How i can compare two dataset return from diffrent operation in Jmeter ? 
First data returns from JDBC PreProcessor - Declear variable StCode and data returns in below mention format
StCode_1 = abc
StCode_2 = ad
StCode_3 = abcd
StCode_4 = adw
StCode_5 = abcq
StCode_6 = adr

Second data returns from JSON Extractor - Declear variable StCodeJson and data returns in below mention format
StCodeJson_1 = abc
StCodeJson_2  = ad
StCodeJson_3 = abcd
StCodeJson_4 adw
StCodeJson_5  = abcq
StCodeJson_6 = adr

I want to compare StCode  and StCodeJson, Can we store both data in string or list? Or how we can proceed with other ways ?How i can compare two dataset return from diffrent operation in Jmeter ? 
First data returns from JDBC PreProcessor - Declear variable StCode and data returns in below mention format
StCode_1 = abc
StCode_2 = ad
StCode_3 = abcd
StCode_4 = adw
StCode_5 = abcq
StCode_6 = adr

Second data returns from JSON Extractor - Declear variable StCodeJson and data returns in below mention format
StCodeJson_1 = abc
StCodeJson_2  = ad
StCodeJson_3 = abcd
StCodeJson_4 adw
StCodeJson_5  = abcq
StCodeJson_6 = adr

I want to compare StCode and StCodeJson, Can we store both data in string or list? Or how we can proceed with other ways?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) for this, it can compare 2 JMeter Variables, for example if you want to compare `StCode_1` and `StCodeJson_1` variables:

1. Add Response Assertion as a child of the request which you want to fail if the comparison fails
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: `JMeter Variable` - > `StCode_1`
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
   - Patterns to Test: `${StCodeJson_1}`

     [image: JMeter Response Assertion]
3. If there will be a mismatch - JMeter will fail the parent Sampler and report the reason as an Assertion Failure message:

   [image: JMeter Compare Variables]

You can also use [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) to compare all the variables in one shot using some form of [For Loop](http://grails.asia/groovy-for-loop-examples).

Check out [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more details on conditionally failing JMeter samplers using Assertions.

Comment: I have to comapre entire data set.

Comment: Then in JSR223 Assertion use the code like: `for(inti=1;i<=Integer.parseInt(vars.get('StCodeJson_matchNr'));i++){if(!vars.get('StCodeJson_'+i).equals(vars.get('StCode_'+i))){AssertionResult.setFailure(true)AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Variables mismatch')}}`. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Can we store both dataset in array or list >

Comment: Thanks for reply!!
I used this code, getting below mention error -
Assertion failure message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: i for class: Script4